# Rates Of Changes Calculus 1

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The cost, in dollars, of producing $x$ units of a certain commodity is

$$c(x)=920 + 2x - 0.02x^2 + 0.00007x^3$$

**(a)** find the marginal cost function.

**(b)** find $C'(100)$and explain its meaning

**(c)** Compare $C'(100)$ with the cost of producing the $101$st item

Comment: @mir What have you tried?

Comment: @mir This is not a site where you can just dump homework problems and expect an answer back.

Answer (score 0):

the marginal cost function is $C'(x)=2 - 0.04 x + 0.00021 x^2$

$C'(100)=0.1$ means that
the marginal cost at $x = 100$ units is $\$\,0.10$

The cost of $101$st unit is $C(101)-C(100)=\$0.1011>\$0.10$